# Data is not loading using http get request in Fusion Chart with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion chart with Angular js, data is arriving from json using get request but not loaded to chart. Message "no data to display" is displayed.here is my controller code.

```
var myApp=angular.module('angularApp',[]);

myApp.controller('countByOperator',function($scope,$http)
{
   $http.get("angular/controllers/data/callcountbyoperator.json").success(function(response){
    $scope.dataSource=response.data;
    alert($scope.dataSource);

    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
        var countByOperator=new FusionCharts({
            type:'bar2d',
            renderAt:'countByOperator',
            width:'450',
            dataFormat:'json',
            dataSource:$scope.dataSource
        });
        countByOperator.render();
    });
   });  
});
```

This is my html code here:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #161616; margin:25px 0;" >
<div class="alBarHead">CALL COUNT BY OPERATORS</div>
<div id="countByOperator" ng-controller="countByOperator"  ng-init="" ng-    model="dataSource"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(response)`.

Comment: this is the error message i get in consoleUncaught RuntimeException: #03091456 chartobject-5.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you are using [fusioncharts angular-js plugin](http://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/), there is no need to do this

```
FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var countByOperator=new FusionCharts({
        type:'bar2d',
        renderAt:'countByOperator',
        width:'450',
        dataFormat:'json',
        dataSource:$scope.dataSource
    });
    countByOperator.render();
});
```

If you change the model by doing `$scope.dataSource=response.data;` simply, angularjs (and in turn fusioncharts) update the view automatically. Thats the whole point of using it.
And your html would be as simple as

```
<fusioncharts 
width="60" 
height="400"
type="column2d"
datasource="{{myDataSource}}"
></fusioncharts>
```

inside a controller.

**If you are not using the plugin**
Change the html to

```
<div ng-controller="countByOperator">
    <div id="countByOperator"></div>
</div>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actual problem was just my ignorance of assigning response.data in place of response. Solved now